# inline-block divs messing up with float and divs inside them

Tags: html, css

I'm relatively new to the coding scene here and I'm trying to create a pen on CodePen. Basically, I want to have two divs on each side of the screen acting as "menus" and then I'll use jquery to have information shown in the middle of the screen when you click on a div that will eventually be inside these div menus.

Unfortunately, I am struggling in getting the "menu" divs to get text inside them while staying in line together. I've tried a few things and I can't seem to get the text inside the divs, and sometimes I mess up the positioning while I'm trying to get text inside.

I've now reached the point where I have the two "menu" divs where I want them but I can't seem to add text to them. I'm not even fully sure how I got them there, the whole inline-block and float thing is stumping me at the minute.

If anyone could show me how to have some divs/texts to these divs without messing up their positioning that would be great :)

http://codepen.io/EoinTrainor11/pen/ojabxR

HTML:

```
<div class="names_experiment">
    <div id="hero_names_experiment"></div>
        <div id="hero_names"><h1>Test1<h1></div>
    <div id="villain_names_experiment"></div>
        <div id="villain_names"><h1>Test2</h1></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#hero_names_experiment {
  height: 740px;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 30px;
  opacity: 0.75;
  positon: relative;
}
#villain_names_experiment {
  height: 740px;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: yellow;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 16px;
  opacity: 0.75;
  position: relative;
}
.names_experiment {

}

#hero_names {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
}
#villian_names {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added `<p>` tags to `hero_names_experiment` & `villain_names _expirament` you can add `<a>` tags or whatever.

```
div id="poem">
      <p id="one_ring_to_rule_them_all"> One Ring to rule them all</p>
      <p id="one_ring_to_find_them"> One Ring to find them</p>
      <p id="one_ring_to_bring_them_all_and_in_the_darkness_bind_them">One Ring to bring them all and in the darkness bind them
      </p>
    </div>

    <div id="heroes" class="type">
      <h1>Heroes</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="villains" class="type">
      <h1>Villains</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="names_experiment">
      <div id="hero_names_experiment">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris imperdiet tortor sit amet dui eleifend dictum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed varius eget purus ut hendrerit. Integer gravida lacus ut tempus bibendum. Mauris faucibus ex ut ante tincidunt bibendum. Suspendisse venenatis eros id justo sagittis, et pretium lacus faucibus. Nam tempus, massa eget aliquet varius, turpis enim commodo nulla, vitae rhoncus sem mauris at sapien. Integer dignissim nibh libero, at mollis ante luctus id. Cras in tristique arcu. Etiam scelerisque nec lacus ut ultrices. In sed libero in sapien congue pretium. Pellentesque at nisi purus. Sed dapibus eleifend diam a consectetur. Aliquam diam lectus, accumsan eu lacus ut, sollicitudin dapibus justo. Duis ullamcorper diam leo, vel molestie ex molestie nec. Aenean efficitur porta commodo.
    Nunc faucibus dictum dign</div>
        <div id="hero_names"><h1>Hello<h1></div>
      <div id="villain_names_experiment">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris imperdiet tortor sit amet dui eleifend dictum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed varius eget purus ut hendrerit. Integer gravida lacus ut tempus bibendum. Mauris faucibus ex ut ante tincidunt bibendum. Suspendisse venenatis eros id justo sagittis, et pretium lacus faucibus. Nam tempus, massa eget aliquet varius, turpis enim commodo nulla, vitae rhoncus sem mauris at sapien. Integer dignissim nibh libero, at mollis ante luctus id. Cras in tristique arcu. Etiam scelerisque nec lacus ut ultrices. In sed libero in sapien congue pretium. Pellentesque at nisi purus. Sed dapibus eleifend diam a consectetur. Aliquam diam lectus, accumsan eu lacus ut, sollicitudin dapibus justo. Duis ullamcorper diam leo, vel molestie ex molestie nec. Aenean efficitur porta commodo.

    Nunc faucibus dictum dign</div>
          <div id="villain_names"><h1>Hello2</h1>
          </div>
    </div>
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/XmxXxG)